# SQL Server 2008, Convert String to Real

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to convert string for example '0.600 KG' to real. I have tried convert and cast but it generate error message. The example is as bellow.

```
select cast('0.600 KG' as real)
Error converting data type varchar to real.
```

Please Help to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the units always appear at the end of the string, you could try taking an appropriate substring, e.g.

```
DECLARE @mass VARCHAR(50);
SET @mass = '0.600 KG';

SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@mass, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @mass) - 1) AS real);
```

Of course, the notion of units would then be lost, and you would just have a real number.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Unit is not required.